# YouTube Player plays previous video ID after refreshing with new video ID

Tags: android, youtube

I am using YouTubePlayerSuportFragment to load the video. It doesn't play current video ID instead it plays video from previous ID. Whenever i clear data from the settings of the android app the YouTubePlayer plays current video ID. How to ignore or skip cache on the YouTubePlayer?

```
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerSupportFragment).commit();
    youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(LinkConfig.API_KEY_ANDROID, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(SplashScreen.mainData.getVod().getCount().getPopular());
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(true);
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 1).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "errorMessage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code if you have cache mechanism. If you have cache enable it may have been a problem. I remove my cache mechanism and it works.